# Mysql Subquery between specific dates

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I'm a newbie to MySQL querying and need some assistance with the subqueries.
I am using ASP .NET charting control that retrieves data from MySQL.I want to display a drill down chart and need some help on MySQL subquery.

Below is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `runtime` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `app` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `process` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Step 1 :
Showing a pie chart of Top 10 users with highest time between 2 dates.

I get the top 10 users used between 2 dates using the below query:

```
SELECT username ,SUM(runtime) as Runtime, 
process,ROUND(SUM(runtime/201600),2) as 'Total Time',
role ,
date 
FROM data 
WHERE   `date` BETWEEN 'date1' AND  'date2'
Group BY process LIMIT 10.
```

Step 2:
When user clicks on the individual user in chartArea, I wan to display the top 10 apps/process between specific dates.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: You are anyways fetching all the data `app/process`. So, where is the issue here. This question looks more of `ASP.NET` related rather `MySQL`.

Comment: Hi ,Sorry if its confusing but my question is about the step 2 where I need to construct the MySQL query "When user clicks on the individual user in chartArea, I wan to display the top 10 apps/process between specific dates of that specific user".

Comment: Hi Rahul,Its not about ASP.NET My query title also clearly mentions its about MySQL.I just gave a brief details on the requirement.

Comment: You're misusing the infamous MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. This might be driving you crazy. Read this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html  `GROUP BY username, process, role, date` are needed.